# Запятые при повторяющихся союзах с однородными придаточными

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, спп, сложное-предложение

> Я готов сделать это, когда поступит заказ, и когда подмастерье будет в кузне, и когда мне поступит железо.

Comment: Всё правильно. Но можно и без второй запятой, в зависимости от паузы и задумки.

Answer (score 5):

Предложение оформлено правильно.

[Знаки препинания в сложноподчиненном предложении с несколькими придаточными](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139)

> **4.** При повторяющихся сочинительных союзах между соподчиненными придаточными частями сложноподчиненного предложения ставится **запятая:** *Находясь в госпитале, он вспоминал, **как фашисты напали на них внезапно, и как они оказались в окружении, и как отряду всё же удалось пробиться к своим.***